# $resource, what's the difference between get and query?

Tags: angularjs

The documentation doesn't seem to specify: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The main difference lies in `query` having `isArray: true` :

```
'get'  :  {method:'GET'},
'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
```

This means you would use `get` when requesting a single object, and `query` when requesting a collection. For example:

```
Users.get({userId:123}); // returns a single user
Users.query(); // returns a collection of all users.
```